# What is the difference between navigation.goBack and navigation.dispatch(e.data.action) in react native android

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I am new to react native and I have react native app for android and I am using Navigation 5 for navigating to the next page. The application workflow is loginScreen -> HomeScreen -> ExistingStockScreen -> ScanSkidBarcodeScreen -> ScanItemsScreen.
I am handling backbutton press with this code on ScanItemScreen.

```
 navigation.addListener('beforeRemove', (e) => {
 // Prevent default behavior of leaving the screen
            e.preventDefault();
            if (this.state.items[0].barCode !== "" && this.state.items[5].barCode !== "") {
             
                Alert.alert(
                    'Error!',
                    'You can only scan six items at a time.',
                    [
                    { text: "OK", style: 'cancel', onPress: () => { } },
                    ]
                );
            }
            else if (this.state.items[0].barCode !== "") {
              
                Alert.alert(
                    'Attention!',
                    'You have unsaved items. Please click on UPDATE STATUS first and go back.',

                    [{ text: "OK", style: 'cancel', onPress: () => { } },
                    {
                       text: 'Go Back',
                        style: 'destructive',
                        // If the user confirmed, then we dispatch the action we blocked earlier
                        // This will continue the action that had triggered the removal of the screen
                        onPress: () => navigation.dispatch(e.data.action),
                    },]

                );
            } else {
                navigation.dispatch(e.data.action)
            }
        })
    }
```

However navigation.dispatch(e.data.action) code is going to back screen but it logs out the user for some reason.
So I am thinking to use navigation.goBack() instead.
What's the difference between navigation.goBack() and navigation.dispatch(e.data.action) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `beforeRemove` event is triggerred when the screen is being removed, which can happen because of various reasons (such as a `reset` or another action). While going back is one of the ways to trigger it, it's not the only way.

From the [docs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/preventing-going-back):

- The user pressed back button on a screen in a stack
- The user performed a swipe back gesture
- Some action such as `pop` or `reset` was dispatched which removes the screen from the state

The object in `e.data.action` refers to the action which triggered that event. By dispatching that action again with `navigation.dispatch(e.data.action)`, you continue the action after performing whatever check you needed e.g. prompting the user.

If you don't dispatch the event again and instead try to `goBack()`:

- It'll be incorrect behaviour - if a reset triggered the event, you should continue the reset (or whaetver triggered the event), not perform a different action entirely
- It won't work anyway, because `goBack` will just trigger the event, so you'll be stuck in a loop of prompts

> However navigation.dispatch(e.data.action) code is going to back screen but it logs out the user for some reason

React Navigation doesn't interact with your app state. If your user is being logged out on navigation, that's a bug in your code that you need to debug and fix.